# Слово "упросить"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто в разговорной (и не только!) речи я слышу слово "упросить" (в значении "уговорить"). Является ли это слово литературным? А то мне как-то оно режет слух.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово вполне нейтральное. В словарях оно присутствует без каких-либо стилистических помет. Образует видовую пару с глаголом *упрашивать*.